# Why does printing the first element of a pointer to pointer to a char print the contents of a string?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dereference

Example code

```
int main() {

char *s = "kut";
char **p = &s;
printf("*s:     %c\n", *s);
printf("s:      %p\n", s);
printf("&s[0]:  %p\n", &s[0]);
printf("p:      %p\n", p);
printf("*p:     %p\n", *p);
printf("**p:    %c\n", **p);
printf("p[0]:   %s\n", p[0]);
printf("&p[0]:  %p\n", &p[0]);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*s:     k
s:      0x1043acf46
&s[0]:  0x1043acf46
p:      0x7ffeeb853670
*p:     0x1043acf46
**p:    k
p[0]:   kut
&p[0]:  0x7ffeeb853670
```

How does it come that `&p[0]` (address of `p[0]`) does print out the string `kut`? The output show that the address of `p[0]`is the same as `p` (as `p` is just a constant pointer pointing to the first element of the array).

Comment: `a[b]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(a+b)`, so `p[0]` is `*(p+0)` or just `*p`, and `&p[0]` is `&*p` which is just `p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`.

If `i == 0` then we have `p[0]` which is equal to `*(p + 0)` which in turn is equal to `*(p)` which is the same as `*p`.

And in your case `*p` is the same as `s`.

Comment: Thanks man for the brief but clear answer! Broke my head over this today... Feels good to know now :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a diagram of how the variables all relate to each other:

```
   char **       char *     char
   +---+         +---+      +---+---+---+---+
p: |   |----> s: |   |----> |'k'|'u'|'t'| 0 |
   +---+         +---+      +---+---+---+---+
```

`p` stores the address of `s`, `s` stores the address of the first character in the string literal `"kut"`, which is stored as an array of `char` somewhere in memory.

Given this, the following relationships are all true:

```
  p == &s
 *p ==  s == &"kut"[0]           // believe it or not, this is legal - you 
**p == *s ==  "kut"[0] == 'k'    // can index into a string literal
```

Given that `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`, this also means that

```
*p == *(p + 0) == p[0] == s
```

and

```
&p[0] == &(*(p + 0)) == &(*p) == p;
```

and

```
*p[0] == *(*(p + 0)) == *(*p) == **p
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does it come that &p[0] (address of p[0]) does print out the
> string kut?

For starters you are mistaken. This statement

```
printf("&p[0]:  %p\n", &p[0]);
```

outputs the address of the pointer `s`

```
&p[0]:  0x7ffeeb853670
```

It seems you mean the output of this call

```
printf("p[0]:   %s\n", p[0]);
```

that indeed shows on the console the string literal

```
p[0]:   kut
```

The conversion specifier `%s` used in function `printf` expects a pointer to first character of a string.

For example this call of printf

```
printf("s:      %p\n", s);
```

outputs the whole string literal `"kut"`.

The pointer `p` is declared like

```
char **p = &s;
```

and points to the pointer `s`.

So dereferencing the pointer like `p[0]` or `*p` (that is the same)  yields the value of the pointer `s`. That is `p[0]` is equal to `s`. So this call

```
printf("p[0]:   %s\n", p[0]);
```

has the same effect as this call

```
printf("s:      %p\n", s);
```

because seconds arguments of the calls have the same type and value.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "kut";
    char **p = &s;
    
    printf( "p[0] == s is %s\n", p[0] == s ? "true" : "false" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
p[0] == s is true
```

Comment: Re “For starters you are mistaken. This statement `printf("&p[0]:  %p\n", &p[0]);` outputs the address of the pointer `s`”: It does print the address of `s`, but OP is not mistaken. They said the output shows the address of `p[0]` (hence `&p[0]`) is the same as `p`, and this is true; the output was the same for printing `&p[0]` and `p`. Since `p` points to `s`, `p[0]` is `s` and `&p[0]` is `&s`, which is the value of `p`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil He wrote "How does it come that &p[0] (address of p[0]) does print out the string kut?"

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s", p[0])` means that you want to print a string that start at position p[0] or (*p) and will end when the `\0` character is reached.